# Calculating direction of rotation

Tags: c#, rotation, point

If I have four points in 2D space, which are then rotated m degrees, what is the best/ most efficient way to determine the direction(clockwise/counter clockwise) of the rotation.

I know which point is which before and after rotation.

I have tried taking into account the lowest point and the highest point (based on y value) and comparing the x difference e.g. (+ve or -ve) but this does not seem to be very reliable and I doubt it is an efficient solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any point will do if you have both the before and after coordinates.  Take the [cross product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CrossProduct.html) of the before into the after.  The sign of the resultant vector will tell you clockwise (-) or counterclockwise(+).

Comment: I'm not entire sure what you mean by "before into the after" ?

Comment: You'd have to know how to calculate a cross-product to know what I mean.  A x B can be read as "cross A into B".  It just tells you to use the "before" as the first vector and the "after" as the second.  Cross-product is not commutative.

Comment: Make sure your rotation center is 0,0. Otherwise you'll need to use at least 2 points.

Comment: Origin (0,0) is assumed; you have to use two points regardless - before and after.

Answer (score 0):

do you know which point is which?
if you do, using one of them is enough